# Convert float 1.88 to string HH:MM

Tags: ios, objective-c, time

I wish to display HH:MM at a `UILabel` when I adjust a custom slider. Currently my custom slider is returning me float values, for example, 2.89, 24.87... I wish to take the float value say 24.87 and change it to 24:52 I got everything working at the following code but I think it is not the most efficient way. Can anyone improve it? Thank you

```
- (void)slideValueChanged:(id)control
{
    NSLog(@"Slider value changed: (%.2f,%.2f)",
      _rangeSlider.lowerValue, _rangeSlider.upperValue);

    lblStart.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Start Time : %@", [self floatToTime:_rangeSlider.lowerValue]];
    lblEnd.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"End Time : %@",[self floatToTime:_rangeSlider.upperValue]];

} 

- (NSString*)floatToTime:(float)floatTime {

    NSInteger iHour = floatTime;
    CGFloat floatMin = floatTime - iHour;

    NSString *sHour = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)iHour];

    if (floatMin == 0.99) {  //=== When the float is 0.99, convert it to 0, if not 60*0.99 = 59.4, will never get to 0
        floatMin = 0;
    }else{

        floatMin = floatMin * 60;
    }

    NSInteger iMin = floatMin; //=== Take the integer part of floatMin

    NSString *sMin = [[NSString alloc] init];
    if (iMin <10){ //=== Take care if 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to be 00,01,02,03...
        sMin = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"0%li", iMin];
    }else{
        sMin = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%li", iMin];
    }

    NSString *strFloatTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", sHour,sMin];
    return strFloatTime;
}
```

Comment: Why is 24.87 converted to 24:52?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad as I understand `52 / 60 = 0.87`

Comment: I think so, too. But I want a complete and clear explanation in the Q itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format to show two digits, this simplifies creating a time string:

```
CGFloat time = 24.87;
int hours = fabs(time);
int minutes = (int)((time - hours) * 60.0);
NSLog(@"Time: %02d:%02d", hours, minutes);
```

Result: "Time: 24:52"

'02' is the number of digits.